# Converting byte[] to String Java. Adding a ? in every conversion

Tags: java, arrays, string, character-encoding, byte

I'm making a java code and I want to read from a file, 64kb at a time and convert those 64kb to string. I'm able to read and keep them in a vector but when I try to convert to String there are allways more characters than there should be. For example:

Converting %Çì¢ with        `String s = new String(byte[], "UTF8")` it gives me %????
Converting %Çì¢ with        `String s = new String(byte[])` or `new String(byte[],"Cp1252")`, etc , etc gives me %Çì?¢ which would be perfect if it weren't for the ? . Can anyone help me? Tried every way to convert byte[] to string :(

Comment: Is your file binary to start with?

Comment: `byte[]` isn't valid syntax. It takes a `byte[]` but you didn't show you provided the byte array.. it appears empty.

Comment: What is the *actual* encoding of the text file? Passing UTF8 if it's Cp1252 won't work, and vice-versa. Moreover, UTF8 is a multi-byte encoding, so you can't arbitrarily take a number of bytes and convert them to String: the last character could be split in two or three.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `String` for binary data. It cannot work.

Strings in Java at runtime are sequences of `char`s, and not all byte sequences can be converted to `char`s.

If you need a `String` representation of binary data, use a dedicated format which can do so (base64 comes to mind).

See [here](http://fgaliegue.blogspot.fr/2014/03/strings-characters-bytes-and-character.html) for the full story; there is an example at the end showing why `String` for binary cannot work.

Here is a sample code which will yell at you (ie, throw an exception) if your `byte` array cannot be converted to a string:

```
final CharsetDecoder decoder = StandardCharsets.UTF_8.newDecoder()
    .onMalformedInput(CodingErrorAction.REPORT);

try {
    decoder.decode(ByteBuffer.wrap(yourByteArray));
} catch (CharacterCodingException e) {
    System.err.println("No can't do...");
    e.printStackTrace(System.err);
}
```

By default, unmappable byte sequences are *replaced* and don't raise an error.

And of course, there is no guarantee that a correct byte sequence will take exactly 64k.

Comment: But for example, I need to get all the chars from a pdf for example, pass them trough a socket and get them on the other computer and make the pdf again. And the problem is the ? that appear when I convert the byte[]. Because I think I have to do it to pass trought the socket (I'm passing a message with the body of the file trough the socket)

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it at all -- why don't you just send the PDF as is? Also, in order to extract text from a PDF file, you should use a dedicated library (iText can do that IIRC).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what those characters are supposed to be, but this is the proper way to use `String` with data that is `UTF-8`, if that's the actual encoding:

```
   byte[] byteArray = new byte[] {87, 79, 87, 46, 46, 46};
   try
   {
      String value = new String(byteArray, "UTF-8");
      System.out.println(value);
   }
   catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex)
   {
      // do something
   }
```

Output:

```
WOW...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the UTF-8 needs a hyphen try this:

```
String s = new String(myArray, "UTF-8")
```

**EDIT**

There might also be a problem with reading UTF-8 every time in the String.  The Byte order mark (BOM) will only be in the first bytes of the file, not every 64k.  It might be better to use a `Reader`

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
         new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(myFile), "UTF-8"));
```

AND you might also have a problem printing the String to the console if the console isn't UTF-8 so you have to change the encoding there too.

```
PrintStream out = new PrintStream(System.out, true, "UTF-8");

String str;

while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
    out.println(str);
}
```